# Yaml : Found unexpected end of stream

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, yaml, prometheus

I have written a python code to generate a YAML file(called `targets.yml`), which is read by a popular monitoring application called prometheus. The prometheus successfully reads the YAML file and its contents but it also throws an error in the log like below.

```
level=error msg="Error reading file "/var/targets/targets.yml": yaml: 
line 218: found unexpected end of stream" source="file.go:199"
```

I am unable to get rid of this error, though I close the YAML file appropriately and below is the code for that:-

```
while True:

    create()
    with open('/var/targets/targets.yml', 'w') as output:
        print "opened the file to write"
        i=0
        for item in result:
            if(item != None and item['status'] == "ACTIVE"):
               print item['domains']['partner']
               print item['status']
               output.write("\n\n")
               output.write("- targets: ['" + "https://" + item["domains"]["agency"] + "']\n")
               output.write("  labels:\n")
               output.write("    alias: " + item["alias"])
               foo=item["name"]
           #print foo
               if isinstance(foo,basestring):
                  foo=foo.encode('utf8')
               else:
                  foo=unicode(foo).encode('utf8')
output.close()
print("Waiting for 300 seconds, before relooping")
time.sleep(100)
```

Also I do not think that my file extension makes any difference. Can somebody please suggest?

Comment: How does prometheus expect the file to be structured? do you need individual yaml documents? those are demarkated with --- or ... (I don't remember). And do you maybe need to append to the file instead of overwriting it?

Comment: @PhilipStark I guess it should be fine with how I write the yaml file because if it was other than what prometheus expected, it would throw me an error write away. Instead, it throws an error at random intervals, I wonder if it has got to do with `refresh interval`(default value is 300secs) and my application generation yaml file after every 100 secs(like in application code above). Please note in my case, I have to overwrite the file.

Comment: Then I would really suggest that you use the pyyaml module to construct your yaml document. Maybe you have a yaml syntax error in some cases. What are the possible values of item["alias"] or item["domains"]["agency"]?

Comment: @PhilipStark item[alias] is just a string like "example" and item["domains"]["agency"] is also a string like "ui.xyz.abc.net" . Like you said maybe pyyaml is a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('/var/targets/targets.yml', 'w') as output:
```

This is part of your problem, this isn't atomic. You need to create a temporary file and then move it into place.

I'd also recommend using a yaml library rather than creating it by hand.

Comment: I am sorry but could you please clarify on "and then move it into place.".  I didn't get this part of your answer.

Comment: Write the yaml to a temporary file (e.g. /tmp/temporary-targets.yml) and then move that file to /var/targets/targets.yml

Comment: @brian-brazil
Unfortunately, this still does not solve the problem. I am using this file in `file_sd_config` of prometheus configuration, running  the application that generates this file as a side-car container along with prometheus in a single pod. I have also tried checking if the `refresh interval` causes this issue, because in my application code, I loop every 300secs. But unable to figure out anything from here too.

Answer (score 3):

In my case there was a miss-match between open and close of quotes `"`,
but the error was in another place then the line where it was reported by the error.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT: as brian-brazil has pointed out, this will not *fix* the problem, but it can possibly alleviate the symptoms. So only apply this answer if you absolutely cannot implement brian-brazil's answer.

To elaborate a bit on [brian-brazil's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83591/brian-brazil) answer: The fact that this operation is not atomic means that the other process (which knows nothing of your python script) can read your YAML file before it has finished writing.

If it is absolutely important that you write directly into that file, you might want to disable buffering [(doc)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open) and write your entire YAML document at once. You'd do that by collecting all the "write"s you're currently doing individually into a string and then writing all that at once.

instead of

```
output.write("\n\n")
output.write("- targets: ['" + "https://" + item["domains"]["agency"] + "']\n")
output.write("  labels:\n")
output.write("    alias: " + item["alias"])
```

you'd do something like this:

```
yaml = ""
yaml += "\n\n"
yaml += "- targets: ['" + "https://" + item["domains"]["agency"] + "']\n"
yaml += "  labels:\n"
yaml += "    alias: " + item["alias"]
output.write(yaml)
```

This is not the most efficient way to do that, but for the sake of illustration, it should be fine.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference really, write a file and then `rename` is the way to do.

Comment: I think it would alleviate the cadence of the problem, but it wouldn't fix it outright. That's why I specified it as a solution for if its important to write directly to the file.

Comment: I added a disclaimer.

Comment: @philip Stark Unfortunately, Like I have mentioned on brian-brazil's  answer, none of the suggestion have been able to solve the issue.